# "No suitable client certificate could be found - continuing without client authentication"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509, ssl-client-authentication

I am working on one java application which communicates to some external server using SOAP web services. I have used the stub classes generated using the wsdl of external system.
On the External system they have enabled the client authentication and provide a keystore file in .pfx format

I have create new keystore using keytool command and import the external system .pfx into my keystore.
I have set the keystore path and password as JAVA_OPTS in my tomcat's catalina.bat file

Below is the entry

```
_set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DJavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystorePath -DJavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystorePassword -DJavax.net.debug=all_
```

Actual Results:

The request is getting failed with error No X.509 client certificate HTTP header found in request
In ssl logs it says 
*"No suitable client certificate could be found - continuing without client authentication"*

Expected Results:
The handshake should done properly as keystore is provided to tomcat.

Note : The Same .pfx keystore is properly works with SOAPUI tool so certificates in the keystore is correct

Comment: Sysprop names are case sensitive; use `-Djavax.net.ssl...` with lowercase j.

Comment: tried but no luck